# find minimum frequency of occurrence of a character in a string in only one traverse

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, frequency

I have this simple code, that gets the frequency of occurrences of characters in a string:

```
sally = "sally sells sea shells by the sea shore"
characters = {}
best_char=''
maxx_num=0
for ch in sally:
    if characters.get(ch) is None:
        characters[ch] = 0
    characters[ch] = characters[ch]+1
    if characters[ch] > maxx_num:
        maxx_num = characters[ch]
        best_char = ch
```

now I want to get the worst_char (i.e. the least occuring character in the string) the same way I got the best_char (maximum occurence)

It's obvious I can simply make this via another for loop to check on all characters in the dictionary again then print the one with minimum occurence, my question is: can I make it in the same loop as maximum one without needing to create another loop, this is more of an algorithm question than a coding one.

Comment: Just add a variable called `min_num` with `if characters[ch] < min_num` in addition to the "if greater than max" you already have?

Comment: no it doesnt work, try it .. the point is that u might miss previous values in the list that is less than the newer one while iiterating 

imagine u have s = 1, p = 1, g=1 then u encountered a 'g' then 'g' then 's' , u will then have the min = 2 corresponding to s while the correct is 1 corresponding to p @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: I don't think so. Consider a very easy string `aba`: when you parse `a`, 1 is the minimum number. Now when you parse `b`, it is still 1. When you find the next `a` though, you have to remember that `b` only had a count of 1. This means you need to know the count of each character at each iteration to know which one is the minimum. Your maximum loop works because each character you consider can only take the lead in the maximum race as you parse it, so you can simply forget about other characters you've encountered. This is not the case when considering a minimum.

Comment: @Kraigolas .. yes exactly, the issue is with 'remembering' as u said, the question is : is there an algorithm to 'remember' without having to iterate again

Comment: You might want to look into `collections.Counter` to get the frequency of all letters in `O(n)`

Comment: Remember that if you're comment's that long: you should probably write an answer instead.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid iterating over the frequency dict at all? It will take only O(n) time to do so, the same time complexity it takes to build the dict. If you want to find/maintain the minimum within the same loop, it will only make the time complexity worse.

Comment: @blhsing , clearly it doesn't matter in this case. it only matters asymptotically, so even if its complexity is O(n) , if 1 iteration (with large data) takes a considerable time, I still need to avoid duplicating the time. still if there is a solution at all (like the simple one I used for the maximum) I want to know, assess the cost and then decide best approach

Comment: There's no "duplicating the time" by iterating over the frequency dict since there's no repeated effort involved--you are not even iterating over the same sequence (the first loop iterates over the input list and the second loop iterates over the items of the frequency dict). It is simply the best possible solution. It is certainly possible to find/maintain the item of the minimum frequency while iterating over the input list, but it is going to take at least *O(log n)* each time, resulting in an overall worse time complexity of *O(n log n)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
sally = "sally sells sea shells by the sea shore"
characters = {}


best_char = wrost_char = sally[0]

for ch in sally:
    if ch in characters:
        characters[ch]+=1
    else:
        characters[ch]=1
    if characters[best_char] < characters[ch]:
        best_char = ch
    if characters[wrost_char] > characters[ch]:
        wrost_char = ch

print(best_char)
print(wrost_char)
```

There will be many good letters, and there will not be one
So you will need an extra loop:

```
sally = "sally sells sea shells by the sea shore"
characters = {}
for ch in sally:
    if ch in characters:
        characters[ch]+=1
    else:
        characters[ch]=1


values = characters.values()
worst = min(values)
best = max(values)
best_chars=[]
worst_chars = []

for k,v in characters.items():
    if worst == v:
        worst_chars.append(k)
    if  best == v:
        best_chars.append(k)
```

print(worst_chars)
print(best_chars)

Comment: thx, my question actually is how to avoid this approach ... if possible